# Maximum frequency measured by STM32F10x

Tags: frequency, frequency-measurement, stm32f10x

I've gotten a question about STM32F10x frequency measurement.
1. what is the maximum frequency which can be measured by this micro and its timers especially the advanced timers.
2. what are the limits of measuring the frequency?

Comment: Have you tried to read the datasheet?

Comment: The maximum speed a system counter can count will either be limited by the speed of the silicon, or the speed of the system clock (rant)(if some tedious resampling/retiming step is done with respect to the clock before the edge gets a sniff of the hardware like in AVR (/rant). Find out from the data sheet which it is, and so what the frequency is.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the internal bus speed (HCLK) determines the unit of time you can measure. The max is 36MHz but this will depend on how you have configured the clocks and prescalers. Only 16-bit timers are available on the F10x line.

So 1/36Mhz = 27.777ns

The max time the timer can measure in this mode is: 27.777ns*2^16 or 1.82ms

Comment: If you set up an interrupt on the timer rollover you can extend the measurement time in software.

Comment: If you need higher frequencies, you can divide down the input signal to a lower frequency.  A chip that does this is called a "prescaler".  See e.g., MC12093

Answer (score 0):

For STM32F10x the maximum clock frequency is considered to be 72 MHz, while 32 MHz must be used for STM32L1xx and STM32L0xx.

TIM3 is used as the master timer in output compare toggle mode. TIM3CLK is equal to 72 MHz. The prescaler is set to 0xFFFF.